# Get data from a paginated Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there a way to get all the data from a gridview filled previously with a SqlDataSource? I tried looking to the Rows property of my gridview, but I just see only 50 records because my gridview is paginated; I set the property AllowPaging to false before but doesn't work

I'm using c# with asp.net

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`SqlDataSource.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to retrieve data from the underlying database.

```
DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
DataTable table = view.ToTable();
```

You cannot access all rows in a GridView when paging is enabled and there are more rows than `GridView.PageSize`, because the GridView only stores the current page (in ViewState). So no, there is no other way than selecting the data from database. Another (less scalable) option would be to use  `Session` to store the datasource.